# Do UDP sockets expire?

Tags: sockets, udp

I want to initialize a socket globally which can be used by sendto to send a udp packet at a later time. Instead of initializing the socket when I'm just about to send the packet, I want to initialize it when the program first starts and then access it later at a different time.

Will this cause issues if the socket is sitting there for hours without being active?

Comment: I don't think this is related to C or C++ specifically. It might be better to remove those tags and just leave [tag:socket].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a OS-specific question.

Speaking of Unix-like operating system, socket is counted as *opened file*, so the only resource you consuming is entry in open file table, which is usually limited with ulimit:

```
myaut@panther:~> ulimit -a
...
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

Socket will also take small amount of kernel memory for its buffers. But since it is open file, it shouldn't be closed until you close it explicitly, or your program is dead.

Other operating systems probably have similiar limits/requirements.

However since memory nowadays is pretty cheap, keeping pre-opened socket has much more benefits in terms of latency.

Comment: It isn't an OS-specific question unless you can produce an operating system where they do expire, contrary to the BSD Sockets and Winsock and Posix specifications that apply respectively.

Comment: @EJP: OPs question is "Will this cause issues if the socket is sitting there for hours without being active?". So I tried to cover all issues that I know could arise from socket that wasn't closed.

Comment: You haven't 'covered any issues that [you] know about'. You've just posted an unsubstantiated guess. Where's your evidence?

Answer (score 2):

No............................

Comment: Even I think you're right, it should be nice to elaborate, or give somes references ?

Comment: Sockets don't just die off from idleness.  I'm not going to look for references for that, I just know it.  If they did, I would have noticed by now.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. The socket itself remain valid util you explicitly close it, as if it was a file. However, talking about details, if you bind the socket with specific IP **other than 0.0.0.0**, the IP itself might gone (due to interface down or changed settings) which render your socket un-usable. In case of interface down, your socket can be usable again if it is up again later and have same ip.